# GDI intake cleaning before or after oil change?

Tags: engine, kia, fuel-injection, intake-manifold, gasoline-direct-injection

I drive a 2014 Kia Rio 1.6l engine with direct injection.

I am at 22000km and considering using this intake cleaning product that gets sprayed into the intake.

http://crcindustries.com/auto/intake-valve-cleaner.php

It contains high concentrations of the detergent Polyether amine.

I just did a fresh oil change though, and I am curious if this could potentially soil or diminish the quality of my oil to any degree.

On the website directions they mention nothing about doing an oil change after, but I want to be completely sure.

Is there any potential for this intake cleaning product to contaminate the oil?

Comment: For your other question which has shopping assistance in it, that question will get closed.  Many people on the site use SeaFoam.  This is available in Canada at the following retailers.    https://seafoamsales.com/canadian-retailers/

Comment: Seafoam is snake oil though. I want Polyether Amine, a proven detergent. Thanks for response though.

Comment: I've had it clean out my combustion chambers pretty well on some pretty old vehicles.  We did an '88 YJ that was carboned up very well, we could see it through the sparkplug holes and a snake camera.  We planned on pulling the head so did a seafoam first just to see.  It cleaned it out, very well.  So, maybe it is but it's proved effective on occasion for me.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

The intake valves sit in the path of the intake air. The only oil it is supposed to see is whatever is routed back to the intake tract via crankcase ventilation, which will be combusted and sent through the exhaust anyway.

Comment: Could residue not form in the combustion chamber during the cleaning process that gets wiped into the oil by the rings?

Comment: @ScottF I'm no chemist, but the quantity of oil that makes it past the rings is meant to be minimal. The amount of oil/cleaner interaction is subsequently not that great. Plus, any oil that does make it past the rings and interact with the chemical will experience combustion anyway before being dumped into the exhaust. The amount of oil that interacts with the chemical and makes its way back to the oil sump is quite negligible.